# rails/middleman dependencies requires different versions of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, bundler, middleman

I was trying to add the `middleman-cloudfront` gem to my middleman project, but got the following error. Most of the gems needs `>= 4.0` version of the the `middleman-core` gem, but the `middleman-cloudfront` requires `~> 3.0` version.

How can I solve this issue?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "middleman-core":

In Gemfile:
middleman (>= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
  middleman-core (= 4.0.0)

middleman-cloudfront (~> 0.2.1) was resolved to 0.2.1, which depends on
  middleman-core (~> 3.0)

middleman-google-analytics (>= 2.1.1, ~> 2.1) was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
  middleman-core (>= 3.4)

middleman-s3_sync (>= 4.0.3, ~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
  middleman-core (>= 4.0.0)

middleman-s3_sync (>= 4.0.3, ~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
  middleman-core (>= 4.0.0)

middleman-sprockets (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
  middleman-core (~> 4.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [support for v4 has been added to middleman-cloudfront](https://github.com/andrusha/middleman-cloudfront/pull/23), but not yet released as a new version. You can pull directly from master:

```
gem 'middleman-cloudfront', github: 'andrusha/middleman-cloudfront'
```